# Pipe curl to awk to download and unzip files

Tags: bash, curl, awk

I want to download all files from this section of a HTML page :

```html
    <td><a class="xm" name="item_1" type="dd" href="/data/24765/dd">Item 1</a></td>
    <td><a class="xm" name="item_2" type="dd" href="/data/12345/dd">Item 2</a></td>
    <td><a class="xm" name="item_3" type="dd" href="/data/75239/dd">Item 3</a></td>
```

The download link for the first file is `https://foo.bar/data/24765/dd`, and as it's a zip file, I'd like to unzip it as well.

My script is this :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
curl -s "https://foo.bar/path/to/page" > data.html

gawk 'match($0, /href="\/(data\/[0-9]{5}\/dd)"/, m){print m[1]}' data.html > data.txt

for f in $(cat data.txt); do 
    curl -s "https://foo.bar/$f" > data.zip
    unzip data.zip
done
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this script?
I'd like to avoid saving the html, txt and zip files.

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting that one. The reader should also know about the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1733489#1733489).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bsdtar` command can unzip archives from stdin, allowing you to do this:

```
curl -s "https://foo.bar/$f" | bsdtar -xf-
```

And of course you can pipe the first `curl` command directly into `awk`:

```
curl -s "https://foo.bar/path/to/page" |
gawk 'match($0, /href="\/(data\/[0-9]{5}\/dd)"/, m){print m[1]}' > data.txt
```

And in fact you might as well just pipe the output of that pipeline directly into a loop:

```
curl -s "https://foo.bar/path/to/page" |
gawk 'match($0, /href="\/(data\/[0-9]{5}\/dd)"/, m){print m[1]}' |
while read archive; do
    curl -s "https://foo.bar/$archive" | bsdtar -xf-
done
```

Comment: Perfect! Pipe into a loop with `bsdtar` was the missing bit.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to avoid saving(...)zip files.

Generally numerous linux terminal commands will accept `-` meaning *use stdin* where filename is required. After cursory search it appears that certain versions of `unzip` does not support this (see [How to redirect output of wget as input to unzip? at `unix.stack.exchange`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/how-to-redirect-output-of-wget-as-input-to-unzip)) whilst others like one described by [`freebsd.org`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unzip) do

> If specified filename is "-", then data is read from stdin.

So if version you are using do that then

```
curl -s "https://foo.bar/$f" > data.zip
unzip data.zip
```

can be ameloriated to

```
curl -s "https://foo.bar/$f" > unzip -
```

If it does not, yet you want to use `unzip` then according to answer from `unix.stack.exchange` prefixing `unzip` using `busybux` will repair that is

```
curl -s "https://foo.bar/$f" > busybux unzip -
```